# Using non-english characters for username causes an exception in login

Tags: java, xml

I am using Wicket framework in my web application. If I use non-english characters like "å" or "ö" for username (i.e.: Björn) I get the following exception when I try to login:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value, consider BASE64 encoding your value
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.maybeQuote2(ServerCookie.java:340)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.appendCookieValue(ServerCookie.java:253)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:958)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:341)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebResponse.addCookie(WebResponse.java:86)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.persistence.CookieValuePersister.save(CookieValuePersister.java:277)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.persistence.CookieValuePersister.save(CookieValuePersister.java:97)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$12.onFormComponent(Form.java:1291)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent$AbstractVisitor.formComponent(FormComponent.java:107)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.visitFormComponentsPostOrderHelper(FormComponent.java:421)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.visitFormComponentsPostOrderHelper(FormComponent.java:408)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.visitFormComponentsPostOrder(FormComponent.java:385)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.visitFormComponentsPostOrder(Form.java:1089)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.persistFormComponentData(Form.java:1280)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:874)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:808)
>       ... 27 common frames omitted

What can I do to allow users entering non-english characters?

Comment: Encode your data in BASE64 before saving to cookie as error message suggest.

Comment: Thanks! but your comment doesn't help!!

Comment: Change the place where you save username and password to encode them in BASE64. And the place where you read the fields to decode from BASE64. Concrete encoder/decoder implementations depends from the place you will call them, so I can't help with choosing one. Also if this also don't help, try to describe what you've tried, maybe then someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of `CookieValuePersister`, it does not load or save to XML at all.  Rather it is "persisting" the cookie by adding it to the cookies to be set in the user's browser.

And that leads us to what the real problem is.  The [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) RFC say that a cookies value must be sent as as printable ASCII characters.  If the value may contain other characters, it needs to be encoded in something like base64.

That is also what the exception message is saying, though you *could* use any printable-ASCII-based encoding if you wanted to ... modulo the constraints imposed by the specification.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You directed me to find the real problem! It is not related to saving non ASCII characters in XML file. I get the exception whenever I login to my web application by a username with non-English characters like "ö" or "ä" even if the username is not saved in the config file. This does not happen for password as they are typed by dots. I think I should change something somewhere related to encoding! Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried doing what I suggested in my answer, and what yatul suggested in his comment?  Use base64 to encode the value of the cookie that you are setting.

Comment: I cannot do that because I am using UTF-8!